# 404 Error when using a PPA

Tags: ppa

i was trying to install winusb

typed in the terminal

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight && sudo apt-get update`

then got that error when tried to update

> Err:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
>     404  Not Found

tried this commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/packagefixes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install banish404
```

got same error

Comment: which ubuntu are you using

Comment: using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: FYI, Google helps enormously with these simple questions

Comment: i saw this topic and tried to use the ways on it but failed

Comment: FYi u when i use google only ask.ubuntu shows up

Comment: sorry if that sounds rude. Actually I searched with 404 and PPA words and the question came first. It also saves your time. And regarding your winusb question, You should try existing questions on AskUbuntu. If those aren't helpful, Ask a new question describing in detail how you failed installing winusb. :)

Answer (score 0):

The ppa you are using doesn't currently have files for Ubuntu 16.04 i.e Xenial Xerus. So when you try to add a ppa it will look for xenial dist being available. The 404 error simply means its not available.

You can probably wait until they update their ppa for xenial or look for an alternative ppa with xenial based packages.

[image: Repository List of the ppa]